# CSS columns not working with images

Tags: css, masonry, css-multicolumn-layout

I have four images with different heights and I would like to do a masonry-like column grid using CSS columns. The following CodePen example doesn't fill the third column when setting `columns` to 3:

https://codepen.io/glennreyes/pen/pwjOmy

```css
.columns {
  columns: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="" />
  <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/500" alt="" />
  <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/600" alt="" />
  <img class="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" alt="" />
</div>
```

I want three images at the top and the fourth image to one column underneath. What am I missing to fill the content from top/left to bottom/right in a masonry style correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the source of the problem is the `display` value of the images.

Images are, by default, `display: inline`.

If you switch them to `display: block`, the `column` property works.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWvVXj)